# How do I get a list of all the partitioned tables and partitioning details in my Teradata?

Tags: metadata, teradata

How do I get a list of all the partitioned tables in teradata?

and

How do I get a partitioning columns and details for a table  in teradata ?

Answer (score 3):

`dbc.PartitioningConstraintsV` contains info about all partitioned tables.

`SHOW TABLE mytable` returns the `CREATE TABLE` statement for this particular table.

Answer (score 1):

If a Index_type is defined ‘P’ that will be Primary partition index , If Table is Partition under these AMP this value will be Q
And for each Q defined you can use further query to get partition table details from  this table

```
SEL *
FROM dbc.indexconstraints
WHERE databasename = database
AND tablename = 'store_sales'
AND constrainttype = 'Q' ;
```